# How to sort only last few lines of a .txt file

Tags: shell

I am new to Linux and i am trying to sort my text file which is called test.txt  and sort it in an descending order and output only the last 10 name into a new file?

This is the content of my test.txt

```
Warchief
Bad Man
Skeleton
Grave
Bobby
Annie
Gourmet
Minions
Flame
Tessa
Miner
Worker
Pan
```

I know that i need to use

```
sort -r test.txt > test2.txt
```

But i do not know how to sort only the output of last 10 names into test2.txt

Comment: [man head](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) piped to sort:

```
tail -n 10 test.txt | sort -r > test2.txt
```

if you want to sort first, just switch the commands

```
sort -r test.txt | tail -n 10 > test2.txt
```